# How to count html tags and contents

Tags: php, html, regex, tags

I have a problem with regular expressions!
How can i count html tags with regex?

Comment: You're joking, aren't you? If not, no, you can't and you shouldn't. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Just count the number of `<` - this will give you the same kind of precision you can get with a regex.

Comment: Also, even if you're prepared to deal with the problems of using it,  regex doesn't do counting. At the very least you have to use, e.g., perl to load the html into a variable and do a split() on "<" (excluding "<!--"), then check the length of the resulting array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regexp use the DOM. I am not sure how you would do it but it will almost certainly be easier with the DOM:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Thanks. DomDocument class is good, and solve my problem, but i have one last question. 
i have meta tags:
<meta name="keywords" content="some something everything"/> 
i need the name - (keywords) and
the content - (some something everything).
How can i get the name and the content with DomDocument class?

Comment: $meta = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $meta->length; $i++) {
    echo $meta->item($i)->getAttribute('name')." - ".$meta->item($i)->getAttribute('content')."<br />";
}

Answer (score 1):

You don't! Why don't you try the [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not designed to do that. There sure is a better solution to your problem, just check the other answers.

If you just need this once, as a quick and dirty hack, and do not care about edge cases (like escaped tags used in strings), you could use `"<\w+"` to match the starting tags, and count the number of matches.

But you should not do it this way. =)

Answer (score 1):

```
$data=file_get_contents("file");
$data=preg_replace("/\n+|[[:blank:]]+/","",$data);
print "number of tags: ". substr_count($data, '<');
```